# Crear usb live con datos persistentes a través de terminal

Tags: usb

¿ Utilizando la terminal y el comando dd u otro comando, es posible crear un usb live con datos persistentes (que guarde y escriba los datos de tus sesiones con el usb live)?

Estoy utilizando dd de esta forma para crear un usb live para crear un usb con una distribución Linux:
sudo dd if=nombre_de_la_distro_linux.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=1M

pero me falta incluir la posibilidad de escritura de datos.

Alguna idea?